# DialogFrament buttons not shown in landscape

Tags: android, listview, dialog, dialogfragment

I implemented a DialogFragment with single choice list, a custom view with a checkbox and a positive and negative button in this way:

```
  @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), ThemeUtils.getDialogTheme(getActivity()));
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_layout_with_checkbox, null);
    builder.setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.categories))
            .setSingleChoiceItems(categories, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   //...
                }
            });

    builder.setPositiveButton(getContext().getString(R.string.apply), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //...
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    return builder.create();
}
```

obtaining this in portrait:
[image: portraint]

but in landscape I got this:
[image]

As you can see, buttons are checkbox are disappeared. I think the issue has to do with listview height that does not let enough space for other views.

I would like to get rid of this behavior and allow my dialog do appear entirely (with buttons and checkbox).

Comment: Can you post the content of `simple_layout_with_checkbox` ?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>